# How do I get posted data in MVC Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

I am trying to post some data to a ASP.NET MVC Controller Action. Current I am trying to use WebClient.UploadData() to post several parameters to my action.

The following will hit the action but all the parameters are null. How can get the posted data from the http request?

```
string postFormat = "hwid={0}&label={1}&interchange={2}localization={3}";
var hwid = interchangeDocument.DocumentKey.Hwid;
var interchange = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(sw.ToString());
var label = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PreviewLabel"];
var localization = interchangeDocument.DocumentKey.Localization.ToString();

string postData = string.Format(postFormat, hwid, interchange, label, localization);

using(WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
   client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
   client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
   byte[] postArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
   client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "pplication/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   byte[] reponseArray = client.UploadData("http://localhost:6355/SymptomTopics/BuildPreview",postArray);
   var result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(reponseArray);
   return result;
}
```

Here is the Action I am calling

> public ActionResult
>   BuildPreview(string hwid, string
>   label, string interchange, string
>   localization) {
>       ... }

When this Action is reached all the parameters are null.

I have tried using the WebClient.UploadValue() and passing the data as a NameValueCollection. This method always returns a status of 500 and because I am making this http request from within the MVC application I cannot find a way to bebug this.

Any help getting this resolved would be super helpful.

-Nick

I corrected the Header to read:

```
client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Now UploadData just errors immediately with with server error 500.

Comment: your content type looks broken. You're missing an 'a' at the front of `pplication/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Thanks.. so when I correct my typo UploadData() just errors with a 500

Comment: Do you have any special routes defined?

Comment: Show us the 500 exception details

Comment: My route looks just like this:  routes.MapRoute(
                "BuildPreview",
                "SymptomTopics/BuildPreview/{hwid}/{label}/{localization}",
                new { controller = "SymptomTopics", action = "BuildPreview"}
            );

Comment: I am sending everything except the xml data in the query string.. those values show up fine but how do I get the XML that is posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the post xml data from the Request objects InputStream property.

```
      public ActionResult BuildPreview(string hwid, string label, string localization)
         {
             StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
             XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
             xmlDocument.LoadXml(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
               ... 

 }
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for laughs have a look in `Request.Form` and the `RouteData` in your controller to see if something ended up there.

Comment: Agree, should be the accepted answer. Here is an example for newbies: string somethingFromAField = Request.Form.Get("someTextField"); - the "someTextField" is from the form that we just sent

Answer (score 2):

As a stop-gap measure, you can always change your controller action to accept a `FormCollection` parameter and then reach in and access the form parameters by name directly.

Answer (score 1):

To get the raw posted bytes from `WebClient.UploadData("http://somewhere/BuildPreview", bytes)`

```
public ActionResult BuildPreview()
{
    byte[] b;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Request.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
        b = ms.ToArray();
    }

    ...
}
```